# With PHP and mySQL I need to join two tables AND enter data into an existing row (update row)

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, dreamweaver

I have other pages where I'm updating the data just fine so I think it has something to do with my inner join.

The two tables are: 
medArt, with the row idMed_med set to primary 
and artistArt, with idLogin_art set to primary and idMed_art set as a foreign key
Both tables are INNODB

Here's my query and the entire code is below it so you can see how I set the variable if you need to.

```
SELECT artistArt.idLogin_art, artistArt.titleFirst_art, 
       artistArt.medFirst_art, artistArt.wFirst_art, artistArt.hFirst_art, 
       artistArt.pxFirst_art, artistArt.imageFirst_art, medArt.idMed_med, 
       medArt.nameMed_med
FROM artistArt, medArt
WHERE artistArt.idMed_art = medArt.idMed_med AND artistArt.idLogin_art = colname
```

Code:

```
<?php
if (!function_exists("GetSQLValueString")) {
function GetSQLValueString($theValue, $theType, $theDefinedValue = "", $theNotDefinedValue = "") 
{
  if (PHP_VERSION < 6) {
    $theValue = get_magic_quotes_gpc() ? stripslashes($theValue) : $theValue;
  }

  $theValue = function_exists("mysql_real_escape_string") ? mysql_real_escape_string($theValue) : mysql_escape_string($theValue);

  switch ($theType) {
    case "text":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;    
    case "long":
    case "int":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? intval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "double":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? doubleval($theValue) : "NULL";
      break;
    case "date":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? "'" . $theValue . "'" : "NULL";
      break;
    case "defined":
      $theValue = ($theValue != "") ? $theDefinedValue : $theNotDefinedValue;
      break;
  }
  return $theValue;
}
}

mysql_select_db($database_connArt2013, $connArt2013);
$query_rsMedia = "SELECT * FROM medArt";
$rsMedia = mysql_query($query_rsMedia, $connArt2013) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsMedia = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsMedia);
$totalRows_rsMedia = mysql_num_rows($rsMedia);

$colname_rsArtists = "1";
if (isset($_GET['idLogin_art'])) {
  $colname_rsArtists = $_GET['idLogin_art'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connArt2013, $connArt2013);

$query_rsArtists = sprintf("
  SELECT artistArt.idLogin_art, artistArt.titleFirst_art, artistArt.medFirst_art,
         artistArt.wFirst_art, artistArt.hFirst_art, artistArt.pxFirst_art, 
         artistArt.imageFirst_art, medArt.idMed_med, medArt.nameMed_med 
  FROM artistArt, medArt WHERE artistArt.idMed_art = medArt.idMed_med 
    AND artistArt.idLogin_art = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_rsArtists, "int"));

$rsArtists = mysql_query($query_rsArtists, $connArt2013) or die(mysql_error());
$row_rsArtists = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsArtists);
$totalRows_rsArtists = mysql_num_rows($rsArtists);
?>
```

Comment: What is your question? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Yes, please let us know what is going wrong exactly. Although I think I can already see the problem.

Comment: Wow, thanks for your interest!  I don't get an error, it just won't post.

Comment: You should take a look at PDO and trying to stick away from mysql_

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: why don't you start the mysql log and check if any query if being fired, this article will help http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/database/monitor-all-sql-queries-in-mysql/

Answer (score 0):

You say: "*I don't get an error, it just won't post.*" -- Does that mean that when you run the code, nothing gets displayed?

Your code ends with

```
$row_rsArtists = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsArtists);
$totalRows_rsArtists = mysql_num_rows($rsArtists);
```

So, there is no code that would display the contents of the table. 
`$row_rsArtists` contains the first row of the result as an associate array (to get further rows, call `mysql_fetch_assoc()` in a loop.
`$totalRows_rsArtists` contains the number of rows returned by your query.

In order for something to get displayed on the screen, you'd need some `echo` inside the loop where you are fetching result rows.